# iterating over dynamically arrray list which internally contain two indexes

Tags: java, list

[image]I am getting an list from Hibernate criteria as shown below ...
[image]

below is also shown snapshot..

can you please advsie how can I iterate that arraylist..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested loop - one for the external `ArrayList` and one for the internal array:

```
List<Object[]> myList = ...

for (Object[] arr : myList) {
    for (Object obj : arr) {
        System.out.printLn (obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterator an ArrayList and Array using the following syntax

```
for(Object[] s : iceReFeedObjectsList){
    for (Object t : s){
        //do you processing here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

Consider you are preparing a  result list with that series.

Ex: `User` object.

```
List<Object[]> entities = resultQuery.list();
            for (Object[] entity : entities) {
                    if(entity[0]!=null && entity[0].toString() !=null){
                    User user = new User();
                    user.setId(Long.valueOf(entity[0].toString()));
                    user.setName(entity[1].toString());
                        //and other props
                    result.add(user);//preparing list
                    }
            }
```